# Algorithm-finding kth next element in an array

Tags: algorithm

I couldn't solve a question can you please help?

```
For i=1 to i=n/2, if A[i]<=A[2i] and A[i]<=A[2i+1] A is called as a "bst"
```

What's the time complexity for finding `kth` smallest element in a `bst` with n elements?

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `A[i]<=A[2i+1] and A[i]<=A[2i+2]`? If it is, this is a binary heap, and you can find the k'th smallest element in O(k)

Comment: What I write is exactly what it asks

Comment: Is this your homework? (rethorical question)

Comment: It's a question in Turkish Computer Olympiads 2013

Comment: amit how can you find it in O(k)?  Answer is O(k)

Comment: Please *edit this question* to change "bst" to "heap", and delete your second question.  @amit: Your conditions are identical, but for 0-based array indices (instead of 1-based, as given in the question).

Answer (score 1):

I can be done in `O(klogk)`, and assuming `k<<n` - that's going to be pretty efficient comparing to alternatives.

The idea is to maintain a min-heap, start from the head (id==0), which is the lowest element, and iteratively add all "new candidates" (which are for a given current lowest `i` - the "candidates" are `2i` and `2i+1`).

Create a new empty min-heap, where each element contains a tupple (x,i) - x is the key in the array, and i is its index

```
set i = 0, currIdx = 0
heap.add((i,0))
while currIdx < k:
currIdx = currIdx + 1
   (x,i) = heap.popLowest()
   if i != 2i: //for i=2i=0, don't add it twice:
       heap.add((arr[2i],2i))
   heap.add((arr[2i+1],2i+1))
return heap.getTop()
```

Time complexity is `O(klogk)`, each operation on the heap takes `O(logN)` (where `N` is its current size), and the heap grows to maximal size of `N=k`, so all operations on the heap is `log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(k) = log((k)!)`, which is in `O(klogk)`.

Comment: This is a good way, but surprisingly enough it can be done in O(k) time (as you say in your comment, but not in this answer...?): http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=176014.  I haven't read the whole paper yet, but it seems intricate and technical, and I find it staggering that students were expected to come up with such stuff (an open problem in CS until 1992!) from scratch in a time-limited setting!

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods:

1. O(k ln(n)) time complexity.
2. O(k ln(k)) time complexity + O(K) space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

First, you mean "heap", not "bst" (the data structure you described is necessarily a heap and is not necessarily a bst).

Second, it's not at all obvious that this problem is solvable in O(k) time -- it was not until 1992 that [Frederickson gave an O(k)-time algorithm for this](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=176014).  I haven't read this paper all the way through, but it's 18 pages of intricate technical argument, and I'm flabbergasted that Olympiad organisers would expect students to essentially come up with it from scratch!  (Or perhaps they expect them to already be familiar with the algorithm -- in which case I would say that (a) it's still asking quite a lot, and (b) it's not a very good question.)